# Vue function fires multiple time

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, console.log, vue-cli

I'm using vue cli and I have function that updates text @click but it keeps running multiple times:

```js
User.vue

<div  @click="newText('Volume')">
<Chart :text=text ></Chart>
volume
</div>

<div  @click="newText('Temperature')">
<Chart :text=text ></Chart>
temp
</div>

<div  @click="newText('Weight')">
<Chart :text=text ></Chart>
weight
</div>

<script>
newText: function(argT) {
        const text = argT;
        this.text = text;
        console.log('text', this.text);
</script>
},
```

In Chart component when I console.log it ran 9 times!

```js
props: ['text'],

text1(){
       console.log('text', this.text)
    },
```

[image: console log showing 9 times]

It seems that since my User component is displayed 3 times(intentionally due to an array of 3 users I have) and there is a box for each measurement(temp, vol and weight), that's why it's 9 times. But I'm not sure why it runs each time.

I would like it to run only once for the box I clicked.
Any help would be great, thanks!

### Update (additional code)

```
User.vue

<template >
   
<div class="user"> 
<div v-for="(item, index) in users" :key="item.id">
 <div>
    <div @click.stop="myFunction(index); newData(index, item.Vol); newText('Volume')">
 <v-touch v-on:doubletap="isOpen = !isOpen;"   >
   <transition name="modal">
      <div v-if="isOpen">
        <div class="overlay" @click.self="isOpen = false;">
          <div class="modal">
               <Chart :text=text :dat=dat ></Chart>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
 </v-touch>
               volume </div>

     <div @click.stop="myFunction(index);newData(index, item.Temp); newText('Temperature')">
 <v-touch v-on:doubletap="isOpen = !isOpen;"   > 
  <transition name="modal">
      <div v-if="isOpen">
        <div class="overlay" @click.self="isOpen = false;">
          <div class="modal">
                <Chart :text=text :dat=dat ></Chart>  
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
 </v-touch>
               temp </div>

    <div @click.stop="myFunction(index); newData(index, item.Weight); newText('Weight')">
   <v-touch v-on:doubletap="isOpen = !isOpen;"   >
     <transition name="modal">
      <div v-if="isOpen">
        <div class="overlay" @click.self="isOpen = false;">
          <div class="modal">
                <Chart :text=text :dat=dat ></Chart>   
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
  </v-touch>     
                  weight</div>
         </div>
   
     </div>

     </div>

</template>
<script>


/* eslint-disable */
import Charts from './Charts'
export default {
  name: 'User',
  components: {
    Charts,
  },
 

methods:{

newData: function(arrIndex, event) {
        const dat = event;
        this.dat = dat;       
},

newText: function(argT) {
        const text = argT;
        this.text = text;
        console.log('text', this.text);
},
myFunction: function (arrIndex) {
          const name = this.users[arrIndex].name;
          this.name = name;   
      },

},

}
</script>
```

```
Charts.vue

<div class="tabs">
        <a v-on:click="activetab=1" v-bind:class="[ activetab === 1 ? 'active' : '' ]">Settings</a>
        <a v-on:click="activetab=2" v-bind:class="[ activetab === 2 ? 'active' : '' ]">Chart</a>
    </div>
    
<div class="content">
        <div v-if="activetab === 1" class="tabcontent">
            <Settings></Settings>
        </div>
        <div v-if="activetab === 2" class="tabcontent">
       <Chart :dat=dat :text=text ></Chart > 

  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Chart from './Chart'
import Settings from './Settings'
/* eslint-disable */
export default {
  name: 'Charts',
  props: ['activetab', 'dat','text' ],
  
  components: {
    Settings,
    Chart,
    
  },
methods: {
    text1(){
       console.log('text', this.text)
    },
</script>
```

and finally I pass text to a chart:

```
<template>
    <div id="container" ref="chart"></div>
</template>

<script>
 title: {
         text: this.text,   
        }
 series: [ {
        name: this.text,   
        data: this.dat,
       
    }],
```

Comment: Please post all the code. I suspect it's event propagation.

Comment: Thanks so much, the code for User.vue or Charts or both?

Comment: Please post both sets of code. Meanwhile, do this `<div  @click.stop="newText('Weight')">` for each one of them and see if it makes a difference. If it's as I suspect, I think it will.

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried it but still seems to be running multiple times.

Comment: I will post the code

Comment: Hi, @YJay, are you sure that there are only 3 users because it seems like there are 9. Also, I doubt this implementation is ideal for doing what you want to do. Could you explain what you are trying to achieve? Why are you wrapping the chart in a div?

Comment: Hi, yes I have an array of 3 users. I think the 9 is coming from 3 users x 3 measurements. Ya it's probably not the most ideal way to do it but what I'm trying to do is when somebody clicks on one of the measurement boxes in user card twice, a modal opens that has a few tabs, one of the tabs is a chart tab which displays the name of the measurement and data for the measurement, so ex. when I click on weight inside John's user card, a chart opens that says weight and displays weight data for John which is coming from the array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219014/discussion-between-tony-and-yjay).

Answer (score 0):

In my case **browser-sync** was the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).